# Htaccess to remove one folder from url

Tags: .htaccess

I have this website in the folder:

www.mysite.com => `user/home/public_html/index.php`

I had to move it to:

www.mysite.com => `user/home/public_html/www.mysite.com/index.php`

Now, I edited the htaccess so that if I visit www.mysite.com I dont' wind up in a double website folder:

`www.mysite.com/www.mysite.com/index.php`

And I did this by these settings (.htaccess):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ www.mysite.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.mysite.com/$1
</IfModule>
```

This works well but only on the root, so if I visit:

`www.mysite.com/page1.html` works ok, while for `www.mysite.com/subfolder/page1.html` it doesn't work properly and I miss some files...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just checking: you don't have access to the Apache configuration? This doesn't like something you want to do using htaccess.

Comment: Right, I do it thru htaccess because I'm on a shared hosting and I have other site with different setups